# Does this series converges uniformly on the domain of definition?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Consider $$\ln(1-x)+\ln(1+x)+\ln(1+x^2)+\ln(1+x^4)+ \cdots \hspace{1cm} |x|<1.$$I think this series converges to 0. Is this statement true and is the convergence uniform? Any concrete proof will be appreciated.

Comment: The series is undefined for $x=1$ and for $x=-1$, so no, it does not converge on $\mathbb R$

Comment: If we consider $|x|<1$? As I can now understand the series blows out if $|x|>1$.

Comment: Please edit your question. Don't leave vital info about the question in comments.

Comment: Related: [Infinite sum of logs puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968300/infinite-sum-of-logs-puzzle)

Comment: *Hint.* The partial sum $$ S_n(x) = \log(1-x) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \log(1+x^{2^k}) = \log(1 - x^{2^n}), \qquad n \geq 1 $$ is unbounded on $(-1, 1)$ while its pointwise limit $0 = \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n(x)$ is bounded. What can you conclude about the uniform convergence?